# String Indices ISSUES

Tags: string, stock, indices

I am trying to get data from yahoo finance in Jupyter Notebook but I am getting error as "string indices must be integers"

```
##code i used
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize']=8,6
import seaborn as sb
sb.set()

amazon = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AMZN')
```